# how to prevent safari adding shades for clickable element

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari

I'm working on a small mobile web game and I got a problem.

I add a click `eventListener` to an element(e.g. `<div></div>`), and tested it on safari(iOS 9). Once I touch the `div` line, it appears a shade which covers the whole `div` and fades out a short time later. Besides, it's hard to take screenshots when the shade appears, so there is no any picture for help.

Does anyone knows how to prevent the shade appears through css or javascript? It's absolutely won't be a good experience in gaming.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tap highlight color to `transparent`.

```
div {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```